# Is my translation of "Me and my girlfriend live in tokyo" correct?

Tags: translation, particles

So I am very new to Japanese (1 week of study) so please bear with me and forgive me for my mistakes.
I will use romanji as i do not know the entire hiragana yet

My translation:
Watashi to watashi no kanojo wa tokyo ni sunde imasu

I do not like how I am repeating Watashi twice. I feel like that sounds weird, how would i fix i?

Also are all the particles correct? The topic is "Watashi to watashi no kanojo", I assume the listener is familiar with my girlfriend hence i used *wa*. If they did not know i have a girlfriend would I have used *ga*? as that is a new piece of information in the universe of discourse?

The particle *to* can be used to connect two nouns in this case me and my girlfriend. *no* shows possession, it is my girlfriend not some girlfriend. *ni* shows location of where the verb is happening.

Comment: Re: not repeating 'Watashi' twice - You will learn that much in Japanese can be omitted, yet still understood by context.  If you simply said, "Watashi to kanojo wa...", the listener would understand you mean your own girlfriend and not someone else's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, your translation is correct. Let's break it down one by one:

> Me(watashi) and my(to watashi no) girlfriend(kanojo) live in tokyo(wa tokyo ni sunde imasu).

The reason you're repeating watashi twice is *watashi* and *watashi no* is entirely different.

I know that it's not the best way to describe it, but it's not the same as saying she's my property(watashi no), and yourself(watashi).

Even if the listener didn't know about your girlfriend we'd still use *wa*, if you used *ga* it'd be translated to *Me and my girlfriend **are living** in Tokyo.*.

I know it's not much of a different, but even small differences are important to a language.

Comment: The sentence with *ga* might be better translated as "Me and my girlfriend are the ones living in Tokyo."

Comment: @aguijonazo Hmm... I don't think so, I'd translate that to *東京に住んでいる**のは**私と彼女です。*

Comment: ^ Well.. these (=私と彼女**が**東京に住んでいます。and 東京に住んでいるの**は**私と彼女です) are pretty much interchangeable, no? 明鏡国語辞典 says: 「一番早く来たの**は**太郎だ」「クラス委員**は**私です」「日直**は**誰ですか」...「太郎**が**一番早く来た」「私**が**クラス委員です」「誰**が**日直ですか」のように、説明されるものを「が」で、説明の部分を述部で示す文に**置き換えられる**。「太郎は学生だ」は、太郎について、学生だという説明を加えるものだが、「 **学生は太郎だ（＝太郎が学生だ）** 」は、ある範囲から学生に合うものを探して、それは太郎だと説明することを表す。

Comment: You're right, I may have been a bit obsessive. Thanks for letting me know.